# Adding databases and a server to a javascript engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, database

I am creating a 2d physics engine with inputs and demo's to help physics students (3d vectors, pendulums etc).

Most of my engine and demo's are done (all written in javascript - canvas), but I am absolutely clueless about creating a login system, using databases, JSON, server-side scripting in order to make this interactive for students and teachers.

Ideas so far are - hi-scores, flagging topics for teachers to go through. (Im finding it hard to find ways to make it interactive, so suggestions would be really helpful)

From what i've researched, I will need to use a mixture of JSON and JQuery but I have no idea where to get started. If anyone can recommend any libraries or tutorials I should use for the project (or how I should get started/ordering) it would be really appreciated. Thanks alot-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login system (In full stack JavaScript).

FRONT END: 
This can be built with a library like react. Obviously the login needs to be a form. On submission of this form, you can post the users data to the database you made to check that it matches. The request to your database can be a simple jQuery ajax request if you decide to not use React. If you do there a request libraries like axios which will help with that. The data you'll be sending will be the values of the input field forms. Email, password, etc.

BACKEND SERVER:
When a user submits the form on the front end, you'll need a route (url) to post that data to. Node is the answer to this. I personally use Express. Either will work just fine. Once you have a simple server running, you'll need to start the base of your API. I like to use an MVC/MC approach when creating my server. You'll need to create a login route. Might look something like this `/api/login`. This is the url your front end will send data to. Once that data his hit your route, you'll need to modify or check that data with a controller. Controllers are you middlemen between routes and the database. This is where you will put any logic needed. When you're dealing with login keep in mind that its a bad practice to store users passwords. So you'll need to encrypt the passwords with a hash. Look into using JWT and Bcrypt for this. I know this is a lot to take in, but I'm just trying to give you the most simplistic explanation. You'll need to create a database, which i'll talk about next. To communicate your node server with your database you can use a driver like sequelize. (Since im going to be explaining the creating of a mySql database).

BACKEND DATABASE:
For this example I'm going to use a mySql database. You'll need to create a database, called whatever. Then inside of this database you'll have a users table. This is where you'll store the information for each user. The table might have three columns. Id, email, password.

Hope this gives some insight. If you have any other questions let me know. Always happy to help a fellow Runescape brother :D

Comment: One thing I am concerned about is how I can fit 'complex, interlinked tables' into a project like this. Most people I know are using SQL, but I have been told JSON is better for use with javascript. I will definitely look into what you have suggested, Ill let you know how it goes. thanks alot for your help - going for 99 programming :D.